# any simple solution for use clojure core async with ring (vertx/ring adapter)

Tags: clojure, ring, core.async

which could be the best way for handle async channels in ring, basically I need get the response of my channel inside my handler and then serve the response

```
(GET "/slow/:a" [a] (slow-request2 a))

;;this function do a slow operation simulating a slow request
(defn slow-response [a]
  (let [ch (!/chan 1)]
    (!/go (Thread/sleep 10000)
          (print "running slow")
          (!/>! ch (+ 1 a)))
    ch))

;;based in the recommendation from http://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/2ka3na/how_do_you_organize_your_coreasync_code/cljbz2q


(defn slow-request [a]
  (!/go-loop
    [v (!/<! (slow-response a))]
    (when v (do
              (print "response v")
              {:status 200 :body v}))))

(defn slow-request2 [a]
  (!/go
    (while true
      {:status 200 :body (!/<! (slow-response a))})))
```

unfortunatelly I get this error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at /slow/10

No implementation of method: :render of protocol: #'compojure.response/Renderable found for class: clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel

seems than the handler is trying response the whole go block instead of my request body, I can't found a solution for handle the response without side-effect except use a blocking response

which could be the best approach in this case?

note: I'm using vertx/ring adapter so http/kit is not an option right now, I need found a way for handle channels in a ring response

Comment: would adding vertx to the question title change it's meaning to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a blocking take on the core.async channel in order to force it to a value. Otherwise the handler will return the channel itself and not the value on the channel.

If you need support for async in your requests consider using [Pedestal](http://frankiesardo.github.io/blog/2014/12/15/give-pedestal-another-chance/)

Also, prefer timeout chan's to Thread/sleep when inside go blocks.

Comment: See? Nobody gets this question because it is simply not asked correctly. My (now deleted) answer was pretty much the same as this one.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin and why did you delete your answr?..I found these libs https://github.com/dgrnbrg/spiral https://github.com/ninjudd/ring-async

probably spiral would be adapted to vertx but it would require an effort and understand than I don't have, just now I'm testing pedestal follow gvickers suggestion..